# What is the name of this song? Is it for voice tone practicing?

Tags: song-lyrics

The mother of pianist, Nobuyuki Tsujii, sings him [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKDdK7LucXA). What is the name of the song? A link to the lyrics, or perhaps a better video of it being sung, would be so appreciated.

It's purpose is to train your singing voice to consistently hit different octaves? Similar to "do re mi fa sol la si do", but is she actually singing lyrics? Is this a lullaby?

Comment: I'm not sure of the on-topicness of this post.  I think the first part is off-topic, but the second might be OK.

Comment: She sings two different songs in the video. (0.07~ and 0.44~)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is a Japanese original song "おもちゃのチャチャチャ."
The second one is a song of "Sound of music," "Do-Re-Mi." Japanese version is "ドレミの歌"

You can find several web sites about them by their names.